# SQL INSERT INTO WITH SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert-into

Not being experienced with SQL, I was hoping someone could help me with this.

I have a empty temp table, as well as a table with information in it.

My outline of my query as it stands is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [#Temp] (ID Int, Field1 Varchar)

INSERT INTO [#Temp]
    SELECT ID, Field1 
    FROM [Other_table] 
    WHERE ID IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
```

So I'm passing a whole bunch of IDs to the query, and where the ID corresponds to an ID in `Other_table`, it must populate the temp table with this information.

Is it possible to save the IDs that did not match somewhere else (say another temp table) within the same query? Or to the same temp table, just with Field1 = NULL in that case?

I need to do extra work on the IDs that were not matched, so I need ready access to them somewhere. I was hoping to do this all in this one query, if that's the fastest way.

Edit:

Thanks for all the help.

Apologies, I see now that my question is not entirely clear.

If Other_table contains IDs 1 - 1000, and I pass in IDs 999, 1000 and 1001, I want the temp table to contain the information for 999 and 1000, and then also an entry with ID = 1001 with Field1 = NULL. I don't want IDs 1 - 998 returned with Field1 = NULL.

Comment: SELECT ID, Field1 FROM [Other_table] WHERE ID NOT IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)?

Comment: Ok maybe I'm missing something, but that will just do the opposite of my current query; I want it to do both in the same query? Or the fastest way to achieve both results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use one target table for each insert statement. therefore, keeping `field1` as null seems like the easy way to go:

```
INSERT INTO [#Temp]
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN ID IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...) THEN Field1 END
FROM [Other_table]
```

the case statement will return `null` id the ID is not in the list.

**Update**
After you have updated the question, this is what I would recommend:
First, insert the list of ids you are using in the `in` operator into another temporary table:

```
create table #tempIDs (id int)
insert into #tempIDs values(id1), (id2), (id3), ....
```

then just use a simple left join:

```
INSERT INTO [#Temp]
SELECT t1.ID, Field1 
FROM #tempIDs t1 
LEFT JOIN [Other_table] t2 ON(t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Zohar Peled. That was very helpful, except I want the results the other way round, my question was not clear. I have amended it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create other query for *NOT IN* Id's

```
SELECT ID, Field1 
into #temp1
FROM [Other_table] WHERE ID NOT IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
```

and other one

```
SELECT ID, Field1 
into #temp2
FROM [Other_table] WHERE ID IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
```

What does it mean *I need to do extra work on the IDs that were not matched*?could you add more detail, maybe we can do it in one query not a separate

**Update**

Where this *(ID1, ID2, ID3...)* come from ? Could we use join ? Than you wil get what do you want if your answer is *Yes*

Try this One

```
SELECT *  Into #temp 
FROM(
  SELECT ID, Field1 
  FROM [Other_table] 
  WHERE ID IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
  Union
  SELECT ID, Field1 
  FROM [Other_table] 
  WHERE ID NOT IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
)
```

or this

```
SELECT ID, Field1 into #temp
  FROM [Other_table] 
  WHERE ID IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
  Union
  SELECT ID, Field1 
  FROM [Other_table] 
  WHERE ID NOT IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)
```

Comment: Thanks, so you reckon I must do two queries, that's what I thought but wanted to make sure. The 'other work' means querying another server to get this information, that bit as far as I can tell not relevant to my question here. I want the temp table to have the information that is found, and the list of the IDs not found easily available.

Comment: @Alex i have updated my answer, You can use _Union_ in this case and result store in same #temp-table

Comment: `case` is a part of t-sql since at least sql server 2000. Unless the OP is somehow working with an older version, then your suggested solutions are over complications at best.

Comment: it only one way how to get this data, you can add your one, i am trying to avoid _case_ statement, yeap you can do the same with case. Thank you

Comment: there are many ways to get the data, the question is which way is the best... why avoid using case?

Comment: As i remember _case_ doesnt use indexes,  i have found this [link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx), maybe i am wrong but its only my opinion

Comment: Irrelevant in this case. comparing execution plans between my suggestion and yours, on a table with 100000 records, the case took less then half the time the union took. (32% vs 68%).

Comment: Yeap in this case better use _case statement_ you right!

Answer (score 2):

The quickest fix to your existing solution is to get all the values from other table which doesn't exists in your temp table. I have marked Field1 as NULL for all those Id's.

```
CREATE TABLE [#Temp] (ID Int, Field1 Varchar)

INSERT INTO [#Temp]
    SELECT ID, Field1 
    FROM [Other_table] 
    WHERE ID IN (ID1, ID2, ID3...)

INSERT INTO [#Temp]
SELECT ID, NULL AS Field1
FROM [Other_Table]
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #Temp)
```

Other way is to include it in the same INSERT statement

```
CREATE TABLE [#Temp] (ID Int, Field1 Varchar(100))

INSERT INTO [#Temp]
    SELECT ID, 
        CASE WHEN ID IN (ID1,ID2....) THEN Field1
             ELSE NULL END AS 'Field1'
    FROM [Other_Table]
```